# Python: Printing a variable declared in __init__.py after importing a class

Tags: python, class, import, module

I have a file called `main.py` and next to it I got a folder called `mymodule` with `__init__.py` and `myclass.py` files inside.

In my `main.py` want to import `mymodule`, but that is not all; I have a variable called, say, `version = '1.0'` inside `__init__.py`, which I would like to print from `main.py` after importing `mymodule`.

The way I *think* `__init__.py` works is that when I import `mymodule`, `__init__.py` gets "ran" first? So I want to test this "theory" my putting a variable inside `__init__.py` and printing it after importing `mymodule`.

`mymodule` has just a simple class declared in it:

```
class MyClassWithCtor:

    def __init__(self, number1, number2):
        self.number1 = number1;
        self.number2 = number2;
        self.multi = self.__multiply()

    def __multiply(self):
        return self.number1 * self.number2
```

I just use it to print out the `multi` variable after instantiating the class, so I know it works and all.

So in conclusion:

- I want to normally import a module which consist of a single class
- But when importing that module, I have a variable called `version` in my `__init__.py` which I want to print from `main.py` after the import.

Comment: What prevents you from putting `version = '1.0'` into `__init__.py`?

Comment: @glglgl It is there, but main.py cannot find it.

Comment: What's the problem with first importing the module using `import mymodule` and then print `version` by using `print(mymodule.version)`?

Comment: @skyking I want to do `from mymodule import *`

Comment: Then you should print `version` by using `print(version)` after importing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't really understand what your question is, or what the class has to do with anything.

Variables defined directly in `__init__.py` are available in the namespace of the package.

```
from mymodule import version, myclass
print version
instance = myclass.MyClassWithCtor(1, 2)
```

Comment: If I do `from mymodule import *` the class can't be found when I do `c = MyClassWithCtor(1, 2)`

Comment: No, it wouldn't be. So, don't do that. (Don't do that anyway, but particularly don't do that here.)

Comment: But I mean why do I need to know anything other than the module name?

Comment: What? I mean, what? I don't understand what that comment means, and I don't know what *any* of this has to do with your original question about accessing `version`. MyClassWithCtor is inside the myclass module, which is inside the mymodule package. You need to import things from where they actually are.

Comment: I mean I guess your answer works as is, but I am wondering why import * does not work, because there are some resources that say it should.

Comment: If you find any resources that say that, post them so we can get that corrected. `from mymodule import *` imports all the direct children of x. myclass is a direct child of mymodule, but MyClassWithCtor is *not*. Seems like you should read [effbot's definitive explanation](http://effbot.org/zone/import-confusion.htm) of importing in Python.

Comment: Thanks for the link, I will check it out. I am pretty new to python so just trying to learn the ropes by trying different stuff. I'll mark this one as solved.